# I have two divs next to each other with the same background color and a white line appears between them

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, background-color

I have two divs that have the same background color and they are one under the other one. The problem is that in some devices a **white line appears between them** and I would like to avoid that.
What can I do to solve it without having to create a background that contains these two?

[image]

Comment: would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: do it with one element instead of two like in the duplicate